# Concerning Lagrange undetermined multipliers

Tags: abstract-algebra, multivariable-calculus

$$\frac{3}{x} +\frac{4}{y} +\frac{5}{z} =6$$ Find minimum value of $x+y+z$?

I'm stuck with algebraic part of solving the equations.
Please help me out.

Comment: I think that you mean $\frac{4}{y}$ instead of $\frac{4}{5}$ ? and please show us your work and where exactly you are stuck so we can help you.

Comment: are $x,y,z\gt0$, or are we allowed to use negative numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Lagrange multipliers, set $$F(x,y,z)=x+y+z+\lambda \left({3\over x}+{4\over y}+{5\over z}\right)$$  Then $$
\begin{align}
{\partial F\over\partial x} &= 1-{3\lambda\over x^2}\\
{\partial F\over\partial y} &= 1-{4\lambda\over y^2}\\
{\partial F\over\partial z} &= 1-{5\lambda\over z^2}\\
\end{align}$$
Setting the partial derivative equal to $0$ gives $$
\begin{align}
\lambda &= 3x^2\\
\lambda &= 4y^2\\
\lambda &= 5z^2\\
\end{align}$$
so that $$
\begin{align}
y &= \pm{\sqrt{3}x\over2}\\
z &= \pm{\sqrt{5}x\over\sqrt{3}}\\
\end{align}$$
This gives $4$ substitutions to make into $\frac{3}{x} +\frac{4}{y} +\frac{5}{z} =6$ to find local extrema.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal value does not exist.

Try $x\rightarrow-\infty$, $y=4$ and $z\rightarrow1$.

For positive variables we obtain:
$$x+y+z=\frac{1}{6}(x+y+z)\left(\frac{3}{x}+\frac{4}{y}+\frac{5}{z}\right)\geq\frac{1}{6}(\sqrt3+\sqrt4+\sqrt5)^2.$$
The equality occurs when
$$(\sqrt{x},\sqrt{y},\sqrt{z})||\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{x}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{y}},\sqrt{\frac{5}{z}}\right),$$
which says that we got a minimal value.

Indeed, let $$(\sqrt{x},\sqrt{y},\sqrt{z})=k\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{x}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{y}},\sqrt{\frac{5}{z}}\right).$$
Thus, $$(x,y,z)=(k\sqrt3,2k,k\sqrt5),$$
which says
$$\frac{\sqrt3+2+\sqrt5}{k}=6$$ or
$$k=\frac{\sqrt3+2+\sqrt5}{6}$$ and we see that the equality occurs for
$$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{\sqrt3(\sqrt3+2+\sqrt5)}{6},\frac{2(\sqrt3+2+\sqrt5)}{6},\frac{\sqrt5(\sqrt3+2+\sqrt5)}{6}\right).$$

Comment: Actually the question should be to find the local minima of the function  x+y+z.But solution x=√3 ,y=√4,z=√5 don't satisfy the initial condition.        3/x +4/y +5/z =6.

Comment: @Amal Antony I added something. See now.

Comment: Could you explain me what property did you use to find minimum value?

Comment: @Amal Antony I used Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.